# Drupal Blog vs. WordPress Blog for a Drupal Website?

Tags: seo, wordpress, blog, drupal

Is there a blog of preference for SEO, when it comes down to Drupal websites. I ask as WordPress seems to have the better plug-ins, though may not integrate as well. Any thoughts on this?  I am asking from primarily a SEO perspective though also a design one as well. In other words, there are so many fabulous blog templates in WordPress and not sure if there are in Drupal.

I seem to be having a struggle finding Drupal blogs to purchase, such as premium blogs.

Answer (score 3):

It really depends on your needs, experience and how far you need to go in the future.

Drupal is a Web Content Management System first and a blog second.

Wordpress is a Blog Platform first and a Web Content Management System second (though that is changing quite rapidly)

- Drupal is a very good, very extensible CMS but requires a good deal
  of configuration do achieve much of the blog functionality that
  Wordpress gives you right out of the box.
- Drupal provides easier access to advanced functionality like workflow, granular permissions and other enterprise oriented features.
- Wordpress is very much easier for less experienced users to operate.
- There are a great many more plugins and themes available to you for wordpress than Drupal.
- SEO wise there isn't much to choose between the platforms from a technological standpoint, though there are a much greater number of SEO plugins available for Wordpress

Answer (score 1):

Well,it depends on the blog requirements.But drupal appeals more to me than wordpress.Drupal is ideal for building a blog with high functionality.